# JQuery - Div is not sliding off the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to essentially 1 page where on a button click all the content slides off to the left and the new page slides in from the right.

I am working off of [this JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ykbgT/1/) from another post and trying to adapt it to my site but i can't see why it's not working.

This fiddle im working from uses this JQuery:

```
$('.box').click(function() {
    $('.box').each( function() {
        if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
            $(this).css("left", "150%");
        }
    });

    $(this).animate({
         left: '-50%'
     }, 500);

     if ($(this).next().size() > 0) {
         $(this).next().animate({
             left: '50%'
         }, 500);
     } else {
         $(this).prevAll().last().animate({
             left: '50%'
         }, 500);
     }
});
```

This is my Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.slide').click(function() 
    {
        $('.sliding-container').each( function() {
            if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
                $(this).css("left", "150%");
        }
    });

    $(this).animate({
         left: '-50%'
     }, 500);

     if ($(this).next().size() > 0) {
         $(this).next().animate({
             left: '50%'
         }, 500);
     } else {
         $(this).prevAll().last().animate({
             left: '50%'
         }, 500);
     }
  });
});
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Please see my CodePen here for the rest of my code:
https://codepen.io/Magicrecon/pen/BRzXRa

Comment: Why don't use only css instead of style attribute for styles? That could keep things much easier to read etc ;)

Comment: Yes thats true, this was just the first tutorial i came across that really did want i was after so i just set out to adapt the same method for mine. I'll look into a pure css way of doing it then :)

Comment: You use *'.slide'* for the click event, but you use *'this'* to animate. In other words, you're trying to animate the *<b>* tag in stead of the div itself. If you slim down the html to only what's needed and change the clicklistener to the div you want to move or change *'this'* with *'.sliding-container'*.

Feel free to ask if it still doesn't work ;)

Comment: hmm i see what you mean, im kind of getting there, if you check the pen now https://codepen.io/Magicrecon/pen/BRzXRa it slides but for some reason it skips the green section completely and the blue shows beneath the red. As someone said, i think i jumped in a bit deep on this one, got carried away with an idea xD

Comment: It might help if you see what im trying to achieve, i've put it on my domain http://lukelitherland.net/

Comment: Yeah I know the feeling :p if that happens sometimes it's best to take couple of steps back and see what happens if you customize one or two things of the existing, and build upon that one :) I'll take a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142425/discussion-between-jc97-and-luke-litherland).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on your previous code, here are pointers

remove the id tag with text `slider` and add it as a class

You have the last two container-slider in the first one. They should be siblings.

See snippet below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slide').click(function() {
    var that = this;
    $('.sliding-container').each(function() {

      if ($(that).parents(".sliding-container")[0] != this) {
        $(this).css("left", "100%")
      } else {
        $(this).animate({
          left: '100%'
        }, 500);
      }
      if ($(that).parents(".sliding-container").next().index() == 3) {
        $(".sliding-container:first-child").animate({
          left: '0%'
        }, 500);
  
      } else {
        $(that).parents(".sliding-container").next().animate({
          left: '0%'
        }, 500);
      }
    });

  });
});
```

```css
#mainscreen-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sliding-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
}

#sliding-container1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#sliding-container2 {
  background-color: green;
  left: 150%;
}

#sliding-container3 {
  background-color: blue;
  left: 150%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainscreen-container">
  <div id="sliding-container1" class="sliding-container">
    <div style="height: 100vh; width: 100%">
      <div style="width: 5%; display: inline-block; height: 100vh; overflow: hidden; position: relative; float: left;">
        <span style="color: white; font-size: 25pt; cursor: pointer; margin-top: 50vh; float: right;" class="fa fa-chevron-left slide-button">&nbsp;</span>
      </div>
      <div class="header-container">
        <div style="height: 40vh; display: block;"></div>
        <p>Click <b style="cursor: pointer;" class="slide">THIS</b> to slide accross</p>
        <div style="height: 20vh; display: block;"></div>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 5%; display: inline-block; height: 100vh; overflow: hidden; position: relative; float: right;">
        <span style="color: white; font-size: 25pt; cursor: pointer; margin-top: 50vh;" class="fa fa-chevron-right slide-button">&nbsp;</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="sliding-container2" class="sliding-container">
    <div style="width: 5%; display: inline-block; height: 100vh; overflow: hidden; position: relative; float: left;">
      <span style="color: white; font-size: 25pt; cursor: pointer; margin-top: 50vh; float: right;" class="fa fa-chevron-left">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="header-container">
      <div style="height: 40vh; display: block;"></div>
      <p>Click <b style="cursor: pointer;" class="slide">THIS</b> to slide accross</p>
      <div style="height: 20vh; display: block;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 5%; display: inline-block; height: 100vh; overflow: hidden; position: relative; float: right;">
      <span style="color: white; font-size: 25pt; cursor: pointer; margin-top: 50vh;" class="fa fa-chevron-right">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="sliding-container3" class="sliding-container">
    <div style="width: 5%; display: inline-block; height: 100vh; overflow: hidden; position: relative; float: left;">
      <span style="color: white; font-size: 25pt; cursor: pointer; margin-top: 50vh; float: right;" class="fa fa-chevron-left">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="header-container">
      <div style="height: 40vh; display: block;"></div>
      <p>Click <b style="cursor: pointer;" class="slide">THIS</b> to slide accross</p>
      <div style="height: 20vh; display: block;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 5%; display: inline-block; height: 100vh; overflow: hidden; position: relative; float: right;">
      <span style="color: white; font-size: 25pt; cursor: pointer; margin-top: 50vh;" class="fa fa-chevron-right">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('.slide').click(function()` 
there is no element with a class `slide` in you html

$(this).animate({
         left: '-50%'
     }, 500);

The element with that Id that you click will get the properties of `left: '-50%'` but it doesn't change anything because the element doesn have a `position: absolute` css value

Before you code this much just change the css manually to see if the jquery rules you add to an element will work.

Comment: Yeah i kind of just thought of something i wanted to make happen and then jumped in a bit deep making it more difficult for myself when i came to test it. I've changed the .slide to #slide which now makes it slide however it still isn't sliding correctly https://codepen.io/Magicrecon/pen/BRzXRa

Comment: @LukeLitherland I guess I can kind of see what you want. My advice to you is to make a div with `overflow: hidden`.
Put the divs you want next to each other and when you click X the two divs slide left or right to show the div that is hidden.